# Pass reference to $this in constructor PHP

Tags: php, oop, reference, pass-by-reference

I've got a class called `Request`. At some point in that class I create a new controller using the following code, passing `$this` in the constructor:

```
$controller = new $this->_controllerName($this);
```

My controller constructor is as follows:

```
public function __construct(Request $request) {
    parent::__construct($request);

    // More stuff
}
```

If I modify `$request` in either this object or its parent object, the values don't change in the object that originally called it. I also tried changing the constructor definition to `public function __construct(Request &$request) {` (as said on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)), but that doesn't work either. How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit 1:** As asked some code that shows what I do with `$request`. The class has a public property called `_response` which has a public property called `_body`. In one of my methods I do the following:

```
$this->_request->_response->_body = $this->_template->_render();
```

Now, I need the request from which I called the method to have the same `_request` property, so that I can get the body.

I forgot to mention that I unset the object right after calling the method, is that a problem?

**Edit 2:** As pointed out below it does actually work, but it somehow doesn't work anymore when I call it from my `__destruct()` function. Why is that the case?

Comment: Can you post some code that shows what you're actually doing with $request?

Comment: Objects are by default passed as a reference, so it is needless to add the ampersand.

Comment: @Endophage: I did so, does this help?

Comment: @GolezTrol: Thanks, I didn't know that. Do you have any idea what causes the problem then?

Comment: @GolezTrol, One of the key-points of PHP5 OOP that is often mentioned is that "objects are passed by references by default". This is not completely true. (c)PHP Manual

Comment: I'd suggest trying the "least code that works" approach, or, if a simple example does not work either, post it here so we can try to fix it.

Comment: @RiaD You're right and yet not. Object variables are variables containing an object id. This id is passed by value. So the 'object reference' is passed by value, which is virtually the same as the object being passed by reference. In either case, the ampersand is useless here.

Comment: @GolezTrol the ampersand is useless here. Yes, I understand it too. I notice it to avoid other people to use your message without brain:) Maybe some one will read manual

Comment: @RiaD Well, I've done so (again) now and next time, I'll be more careful before saying that they're passed by reference. After all it's not the same. In this scenario it won't matter since you can alter the object. But you cannot make the passed variable point to another object without passing it by reference, so in other situations there sure is a difference. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: And there it pops up again: [Modifications in object __destruct() not saved PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986334/modifications-in-object-destruct-not-saved-php)

Comment: @hakre: yes indeed. I figured that, since this question was not really specific enough (and also bad testing from me), I should ask it in a new, direct question. Don't you agree?

Comment: @Frog: Borderline :) However, I think you should add the code of the constructor to the other question as well and you should give your classes names and refer to the names so it's clear what get's assigned to what and how.

Comment: Okay, I'll do that. Thanks for all your help thus far!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Request{
    public $var= 'a';
    public $_controllerName='b';
    public function x(){
        $controller = new $this->_controllerName($this);
    }
}
class controller{
    public function __construct(Request $req){
        $req->var='xyz';
    }
}


class b extends controller{
    public function __construct(Request $req){
        parent::__construct($req);
        print $req->var;
        $req->var='LOL';
    }
}

$r=new Request();
$r->x();
print "\n";
print $r->var;
```

prints

```
xyz
LOL
```

So, it works well in both cases

Comment: You're right! Somehow I can't manipulate the variables from my `__destruct()` function though. Why is that the case?

Comment: @Frog: Because maybe the other object you try to manipulate is already destructed? Try a `var_dump` before you manipulate it and check if it's already there or not.

Comment: @Hakre: I already tried that, and it does exist... The strangest thing is that if I do `print_r` after my modifications in the destructor it actually shows my changes. The changes just don't exist anymore in the class that called it. I really don't understand that.

Comment: Which class "calls" the destructor?

Comment: The destructor is called automatically when I call `unset()` on the object. I know that it ••is•• called, any changes I make to the `_request` property just aren't change in the initial object.