# Modifications in object __destruct() not saved PHP

Tags: php, oop, destructor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pass reference to $this in constructor PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975416/pass-reference-to-this-in-constructor-php)

I'm working on a simple PHP framework as a learning project. I've got a request object with a method called `_execute()`. In that method I (among other things) create an object called pageController, call a method on it, and remove the object using the following code:

```
$controller = new $this->_controllerName($this);
call_user_func(array($controller, $this->_methodName));
unset($controller);
```

As you can see I pass the current object to the constructor of the new pageController. My constructor is as follows:

```
public function __construct(Request $request) {
    parent::__construct($request);

    // More stuff
}
```

The parent's controller is like this:

```
public function __construct(Request $request) {
    $this->_request = $request;
}
```

This all works fine, but there is a problem with my destructor. In the pageController I've also got two other methods:

```
public function __destruct() {
    $this->_render();
}

public function _render($templateName = 'default') {
    $this->_request->_response->_body = $this->_template->_render();
}
```

My `_render()` method works great if I call it from within another method in pageController: I can then get the response body from the initial request object using `$this->_response->_body`. When I call the `_render()` method from my destructor though, the changes are not changed in the request object. When I call `print_r()` right after the call to `_render()`, the changes **are** somehow visible...

**Summarized:** Any changes I make to the `_request` property in the destructor are somehow not changed in the initial request object, which references to the same, since objects are (almost) always not copied but referenced. What am I doing wrong?

**Note:** I asked a similar question before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975416/pass-reference-to-this-in-constructor-php), but that questions was not specific enough (because I didn't fully understand the problem then and thanks to some bad testing by myself). I figured I should ask a new, specific, direct question so someone can hopefully help me out.

Comment: I don't think you should put that kind of logic in a destructor. Destructor should be used to destroy stuff and clean your objects (database connections, sockets, etc.). What if you want to unset the object because you want to unset it (and not render)? Also, `$this->_request->_response->_body` greatly violates the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter). While you don't have to (and sometimes just can't) comply 100% to that principle, it's usually a good idea to shorten those (e.g.: `$this->_request->setResponseBody($body)`) to facilitate testing and debugging.

Comment: I also might suggest you read the [SOLID principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_%28object-oriented_design%29) if you want to learn how to do good OOP.

Comment: @netcoder: Thanks for the comments! I'm still a novice in OOP and have been learning a lot lately while writing my little framework. I basically inspired my own response class on Kohana's response class, which works really well (I think). I'm definitely going to create custom setters and getters in a later stadium (I've read it provides way more flexibility), but this was just a basic test (which turned out to be a bit harder than I thought). I'll read about the Law of Demeter and the SOLID principles tomorrow, thanks for the links!

Comment: @netcoder: And by the way, initially I didn't have this logic in my destructor. But isn't it okay to have it in a destructor when the controller **has** to output the page? When it's the first controller called? Furthermore, I was just trying it out and want to understand why it doesn't work...

Comment: @Frog: It's not a big no-no, but it doesn't make much sense (to me anyway). Keep in mind that an exception thrown in a destructor (or any methods called within) will cause a fatal error, with no backtrace, line number or file name (*Exception thrown without a stack frame in Unknown on line 0*). This is very hard to debug. I avoid putting fancy logic in destructors for that reason.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What PHP version are you using? I was not able to duplicate your issue on `5.3.6` with the following code:

```
class Foo {
    public function __construct(Bar $bar) {
        $this->bar = $bar;
    }
    public function __destruct() {
        $this->bar->value = 'set by Foo::__destruct';
    }
}

class Bar {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->value = 'set by Bar::__construct';
    }
}

$bar = new Bar();
$foo = new Foo($bar);
print $bar->value . PHP_EOL;  // => 'set by Bar::__construct'
unset($foo);
print $bar->value . PHP_EOL;  // => 'set by Foo::__destruct'
```

Is that along the same lines as what you are attempting to do. If it is... it sounds like maybe some other part of you application logic is interfering.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That's not exactly what I need, but I have made a really simple version of what I need and that does somehow work... So you're right and the error must be somewhere in my logic. It's really strange, because I did already make a simplified version, I guess not simple enough... Anyways, I now have to find the error. Thanks for your time!